# How can I have an external JSON data file with my route parameters in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular, and obviously Angular 2 also.  I'm trying to store my route parameters in an external file (ex., a JSON formatted data file).

The closest I've come to getting it to work is to create a .js file with a variable set to my route parameters, and include it.

```
var routeParams = [
        { path: '/',             as: 'Home',          component: HomeComponent },
        { path: '/petlist',      as: 'Petlist',       component: PetlistComponent }
    ];
```

Then use it for the RouteConfig:

```
@RouteConfig(routeParams)
```

But the problem is that the it is expecting the components to be classes, and they don't exist in the .js file.

I also tried having a function that returns the JSON route parameters, but I have the same issue with the component classes.

The system I am working with already has a UI for the user to create web pages, setup menus, etc.  I am trying to have that system output Bootstrap/Angular2 templates.  Because the user can create their own web pages I'm not sure how to setup the routes since they can change.  I thought using a JSON data file would be a good solution, but my app obviously needs to use the route data from that file instead of being hard-coded in the app.

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 and TypeScript.

Comment: whats the reasons/advantage  behind the task you are doing ? actually i think i am not getting you properly.

Comment: Pardeep, the point was to support a website that has a CMS that would "export" it's website as templates and routes.  I ended up doing it with Angular 1 since I could load routes from a JSON file very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if its possible in angular2, unfortunately, You won't find any example like that in the [routing docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), you must manually define the component class for each route. however you can loop over multiple routes sharing the same component. (ex: bookmarks)

Comment: Murhaf, do you know if it's possible in Angular v1?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [resetConfig()](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig) , getting the data from server then reading actual router data with [router.config](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#config) in another array, and pushing the new routes.

```
addRouteConfig(): void {
    const allRoute = this.router.config;
    allRoute.push(
        {
            path: 'someroute',
            component: someRouterComponent
        }
    );
    this.router.resetConfig(allRoute);
}
```